# Python - make dataframe's columns consistent with list elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From what I've read, it's easy to add and delete columns from a `DataFrame`, but I was wondering if there's already a method to do what I'm trying to achieve, in order to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Suppose I have the `DataFrame` `x`:

```
   a  b   c
0  1  5   8
1  2  6   9
2  3  7  10
```

I want to verify whether the column names correspond solely to the elements contained in a list `l`. Case there are less elements in `l` than columns in `x`, I want the missing columns to be deleted.

For instance, if `l = ["a", "b"]`, `x` would become:

```
   a   c
0  1   8
1  2   9
2  3  10
```

On the other hand, if there are more elements in `l` than columns in `x`, I want to create new, correspondingly named columns, with all the values on that column being set as 0.

For instance, if `l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, `x` would become:

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  5   8  0
1  2  6   9  0
2  3  7  10  0
```

I could do a loop to check consistency between column names in `x` and elements in `l`, but is there anything more efficient than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use (addition of .astype(np.int) thanks to @Bill if needed. Note that this converts the whole dataframe to ints):

```
df.loc[:, l].fillna(0).astype(np.int)
```

Case 1:

```
l = ["a", "b"]
df.loc[:, l].fillna(0).astype(np.int)

    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   7
```

Case 2:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
df.loc[:, l].fillna(0).astype(np.int)

    a   b   c   d
0   1   5   8   0
1   2   6   9   0
2   3   7   10  0
```

Comment: Nice.  (Just add `.astype(np.int)` if needed)

Comment: thanks, was thinking to complicated with `.astype(int)` since, originally, i wanted to keep already existing float columns ;)

Comment: `np.int` is just a confusing way to spell `int`. Never use the former.

Answer (score 1):

I think pd.concat might be a way to achieve.

```
In [47]: import pandas as pd

In [48]: data = {
    ...: 'a': [1, 2, 3],
    ...: 'b': [5, 6, 7],
    ...: 'c': [8, 9, 10]
    ...: }

In [49]: x = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [50]: x
Out[50]: 
   a  b   c
0  1  5   8
1  2  6   9
2  3  7  10

In [51]: l = ["a", "b"]

In [52]: x[l]
Out[52]: 
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7

In [53]: l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

In [55]: y = pd.DataFrame(columns=l)

In [56]: y
Out[56]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d]
Index: []

In [57]: pd.concat((x, y))
Out[57]: 
     a    b     c    d
0  1.0  5.0   8.0  NaN
1  2.0  6.0   9.0  NaN
2  3.0  7.0  10.0  NaN

In [58]: pd.concat((x, y)).fillna(0)
Out[58]: 
     a    b     c  d
0  1.0  5.0   8.0  0
1  2.0  6.0   9.0  0
2  3.0  7.0  10.0  0
```

Comment: b.t.w. the reason it converts to floating point type is that integer arrays cannot contain `np.nan`.  After replacing the `NaN` values with zeros you can convert back to an integer array using `.astype(np.int)`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple function that gets what you're looking for. The identification is done using set operations, but then it loops to create the new columns using insert. Perhaps there is a better way to do this one loop?

```
def func_df(df, l):

    # First find intersection
    intersect = set(df.columns).intersection(set(l))
    df = df.loc[:, intersect]

    # Now find list elements not here.
    additions = set(l).difference(overlap)
    for i in additions:
        df.insert(0, i, 0)

    return df


df = pd.DataFrame(
        [[1, 5, 8],
         [2, 6, 9],
         [3, 7, 10]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


out = func_df(df, ['a', 'b', 'd', 'k'])

print(out)
   k  d  a  b
0  0  0  1  5
1  0  0  2  6
2  0  0  3  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Again a function but less complicated,

```
def df_from_list(df, l):
    for i in l:
        if i not in df.columns:
            df[i]=0
    return df[l]
```

Now call the function

```
l = ["a", "b","z"]    
df_from_list(df, l)
```

You get

```
    a   b   z
0   1   5   0
1   2   6   0
2   3   7   0
```